# creating local push notification using react-native - IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I am developing IOs app using react-native. I want to create local push notification by clicking on button. how can I do this? which all the libraries I need to import?

Comment: can you check this : https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification ?

Comment: yep. I followed this, but I have confusion about set-up. actually what are the step required for local notification?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content  In this link, only those Three bullets points are enough rite?

Comment: Here is the link for steps : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content

Comment: After three bullet points, You need to do registration in App Delegate too. Follow that page it shows code too.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW6 how about this?

Comment: Are you interested in local notification or push notification ? Local notifications are scheduled locally on device and Push notifications are pushed from server when something interesting happens.  As far as I understand in your situation you need local notification not  push notification so you don't need to follow above link.

Comment: ok thank you. as of now I want only local notification.

Answer (score 0):

- For iOS Push Notification **You need Apple Developer Account** .
- Then you have to follow the link : https://medium.com/@martco/triggering-ios-actionable-push-notifications-via-react-native-7990a6a3c3f4
- iOS Push Notification only works in Real Devices (iPhone ,apple iPad)